# How to create UI using autolayout which will have expand collapse feature in Swift?

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uitableviewautomaticdimension

**I have a UI to design**

[image: This UI will be without Expand]

[image: This UI will be after Expand]

I need to create this `UI` using `AutoLayout` and i am confused shall i use only `UITableViewCell` to create this UI or i have to create this using `Section. Also how will i work with expand collapse could someone help me in this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can achive this by creating 2 prototype cells one with lesser view and the other one with expandedview and on trigger you can replace cells with animation it looks like cell is expanding..

Comment: @anujtiwari There are many questions on SO about this topic. Read them, try out their suggestions, ask again you've had a go at solving yourself.

Comment: @anujtiwari Add the code you wrote to your question and we can show you where you're going wrong.

Comment: @anujtiwari Autolayout isn't magic, you will have to write some code to make this work. If you can't be bothered to do that, and just want someone else to do it for you, don't be surprised if you don't get answers to your question. Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this in two way **First** creating 2 prototype cells one for Header view and other for details view and **Second** one prototype cells one for details view and create your header in `viewForHeaderInSection` for each section.

`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {`

so it's easy for you to do with first one here is the code.

```
import UIKit

public struct Section {
    var name: String
    var collapsed: Bool

    public init(name: String, collapsed: Bool = false) {
        self.name = name
        self.collapsed = collapsed
    }
}

class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var sampleData: [Section] = [Section(name: "Header 1"),Section(name: "Header 2"),Section(name: "Header 3")]
```

**After setting up data expand collapse uitableviewcell**

```
//
// MARK: - View Controller DataSource and Delegate
//
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sampleData[section].collapsed ? 2 : 1
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sampleData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Header
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "header")!
        return cell
    }
    // Cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailed")!
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let collapsed = !sampleData[indexPath.section].collapsed

        // Toggle collapse
        sampleData[indexPath.section].collapsed = collapsed
        self.tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: how can i achieve this using two cells tell me

Comment: how much offers you have in your data will go in `numberOfSections` and each will expand. so for every section two cell if expanded then detail cell if not then only header cell.

Comment: how's you ui you posted each one has "Click for more info" so that one is your header and that detail more info is 2nd prototype cell.

Comment: how's your json response structure look like explain or edit your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172152/discussion-between-govind-kumawat-and-anuj-tiwari).

Comment: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=978f7cc9c94d4bf58b03fbccbbec2013 this is my json

Comment: i forgot to upvote can u help me with question i will upvote on ur question but plz help me with my question posted yesterday

Comment: can u help me in my question bro i m not getting any solution